# Scrapy DupeFilter on a per spider basis?

Tags: scrapy

I currently have a project with quite a few spiders and around half of them need some custom rule  to filter duplicating requests. That's why I have extended the RFPDupeFilter class with custom rules for each spider that needs it.

My custom dupe filter checks if the request url is  from a site that needs custom filtering and cleans the url (removes query parameters, shortens paths, extracts unique parts, etc.), so that the fingerprint is the same for all identical pages. So far so good, however at the moment I have a function with around 60 if/elif statements, that each request goes through. This is not only suboptimal, but it's also hard to maintain.

So here comes the question. Is there a way to create the filtering rule, that 'cleans' the urls inside the spider? The ideal approach for me would be to extend the Spider class and define a clean_url method, which will by default just return the request url, and override it in the spiders that need something custom. I looked into it, however I can't seem to find a way to access the current spider's methods from the dupe filter class.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement a downloader middleware.

middleware.py

```
class CleanUrl(object):
    seen_urls = {}
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        url = spider.clean_url(request.url)
        if url in self.seen_urls:
              raise IgnoreRequest()
        else:
            self.seen_urls.add(url)
        return request.replace(url=url)
```

settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'PROJECT_NAME_HERE.middleware.CleanUrl: 500} 
# if you want to make sure this is the last middleware to execute increase the 500 to 1000
```

You probably would want to disable the dupefilter all together if you did it this way.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a really clean solution.

Comment: How do you disable the dupefilter?

Comment: @Chris While declaring the rules, don't use unique=True while declaring rules for spider. rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(unique=True), callback="parse_item", follow= True),)